# Hackerrank Beautiful Strings

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, dynamic-programming

> **[Problem Statement](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/beautiful-string/problem)**
>
> You are given a string, *S* , consisting of lowercase English letters.
>
> A string is beautiful with respect *S* to  if it can be derived from *S* by removing exactly 2 characters.
>
> Find and print the number of different strings that are beautiful with respect to *S*.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> A single string of lowercase English letters denoting *S*.
>
> **Output Format**
>
> Print the number of different strings that are beautiful with respect
>   to *S*.
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> abba
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> 4
>
> **Explanation**
>
> The following strings can be derived by removing  characters from *S*:
>   `ab, bb, ba, ab, ba, aa and bb`.
>
> This gives us our set of unique beautiful strings, `B = {ab, ba, aa,
>   bb}` as `|B| = 4`, we print 4

Here is my solution but it's not using dynamic programming. I am not getting any hints about how it can be solved via a DP approach.

```
function beautifulStrings(str) {
    const res = new Set()

    for (let i = 0; i < str.length - 1; i++) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < str.length; j++) {
            let s = str.split('')
            s[i] = undefined
            s[j] = undefined
            res.add(s.join(''))
        }
    }

    return res.size
}
```